# Security tab doesn't show in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

"Security tab" in folders properties doesn't show up. I tried all of the things I found in the internet and the didn't work. I tried all the ways [here](https://computerstepbystep.com/security_tab_windows_7.html). Maybe windows 7 pro has another way? I have administrator rights and I'm currently using another account not the one in PC's domain but I can access the main adlmnistrator account too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying above that all Windows User Accounts do not show Security Tab in Folder Properties?  That is unusual if true for all accounts. Try running SFC (System File Checker). Open an admin command prompt and run SFC /SCANNOW .  Allow it to complete, correct errors, and then close out restart and test.

Comment: @John yes security tab does not show in any of users but I'll try that anf keep you informed

Comment: Also, if SFC does not correct it, then you may need to rebuild Windows (yes, I understand what I am asking of you)

Comment: I've had lroblems with other system files too like rstrui to system restore and Ik I need a fresh windows installation but my whole family uses the pc daily.

Comment: See this, it must be enabled as it is not by default, reboot required>>>>>>http://windows.mercenie.com/windows-xp/how-to-enable-the-missing-security-tab-in-windows-xp-7-8/

Comment: @Moab I have tried it before and did not work. Use simple file sharing (Recommended) is not there. Keep in mind I have win 7 pro

Comment: @John I iterd to run SFC but it gave me this error: "Windows Resource Protection colnd not start the repair service". I tried things I found online like this >> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/sfc-scannow-windows-resource-protection-could-not/3dabeaa4-269d-4c65-ab42-a3cf5ef1092d  but it did not work. I tried to run the scan in safe mode but it still didnt work. I opened cmd in repair mode and the commands starts but the stops because a repair is running and I had to reboot and when I came back to normal it didnt work

Comment: I think at this point you need to rebuild the system because of this and the other errors.

Comment: @John with rebuild you mean reinstall right?

Comment: Yes. Back up documents, email and all and reinstall. If you have the Windows 7 DVD you can try a repair install but fresh is probably better here.